# The ejb-link is unqualified and resolves to multiple EJBs in the application

Tags: ejb

I am trying to build a pre-existing project which is to be deployed on Weblogic Server 12.1.2 - the project has multiple WAR file modules which appear to be referring to the same set of EJB classes. On building the application I get the following error - looking for some clues as to why this error occurs and how I can resolve ?

```
weblogic.j2ee.validation.ComplianceException: [J2EE:160092]Error: The ejb-link   "ProfileServicesImpl" declared in the ejb-ref or ejb-local-ref "ejb/ProfileServices" in the module "bigrez-web-admin.war"
 is ambiguous. The following list of application modules contain an EJB with the name "ProfileServicesImpl": bigrez-web-admin.war, bigrez-web-user.war, bigrez-services.jar. Qualify this ejb-link to re
move the ambiguity.
        at weblogic.j2ee.validation.EARValidator.validateUnqualifiedEJBLink(EARValidator.java:256)
        at weblogic.j2ee.validation.EARValidator.validateEJBLinks(EARValidator.java:121)
        at weblogic.j2ee.validation.EARValidator.validate(EARValidator.java:74)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.CompileModuleFlow.compile(CompileModuleFlow.java:72)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.run(FlowDriver.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.EARCompiler.compile(EARCompiler.java:53)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppCompilerFlow.compileInput(AppCompilerFlow.java:101)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppCompilerFlow.compile(AppCompilerFlow.java:35)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.run(FlowDriver.java:27)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.Appc.runBody(Appc.java:203)
        at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
        at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
        at weblogic.application.compiler.Appc.main(Appc.java:263)
        at weblogic.appc.main(appc.java:14)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.CompilerTask.invokeMain(CompilerTask.java:301)
        at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.privateExecute(Appc.java:261)
        at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc.execute(Appc.java:164)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe using some kind of ejb linking like for example the `@DependsOn("ProfileServicesImpl")` annotation? 
In that case, you need to specify which of the multiple jars/wars containing it you want to use. 
You could for example use `bigrez-services.jar` like this:

```
@DependsOn("bigrez-services.jar#ProfileServicesImpl")
```